# Pass context to twig block

Tags: symfony, twig

How do I pass the variable

```
form.myField
```

to this block

```
{{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}
```

as a context ?

Is there something like `with` for `include` ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried ? {% set myField = form.myField' %} before block

Comment: I'm using twig without Symfony2 and the `block` function just lives in the context. By this I mean, if you define a variable before calling `block`, you can use that variable inside the block. Same happens with `include` or `extend`. So, if you have `form.myField` already defined, you don't need to pass a context.

Comment: With this approach I should do `{% set var1 = form.vars.var1' %}` for every single variable in array `form.vars`. I agree that this will work. My question is how to pass `form.vars` at once so that all its elements will be variables in the `block`. In case of `include` this is done simply by `{% include 'template.twig' with form.vars %}`